# lib-dynload missing in python install

Tags: python, installation

I have tried everything I can think of but I can't seem to get this to work. I am trying to install Python 2.7 (any of them) on one of my RedHat machines. Every time I try to install it it says it cant find _struct. The problem is, there is no lib-dynload directory in the lib/python2.7/ directory. The PYTHONPATH is set to the correct location and I used the --prefix=$PYTHONPATH during the ./configure. It seems to be only on my 2.7 installs, 2.6 is fine and so is 3.1.

I have a 2.7 on another machine, so for the hell of it I copied that lib-dynload directory to the current machine. It solved the ImportError but core dumped on a Floating point exception.

I've been fighting with it for hours. I tried 2.7.2, 2.7.1 and now 2.7. None of them work...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue on Solaris.

The only hint I found on the internet is in this [post](http://mail.python.org/pipermail//python-bugs-list/2011-July/143801.html)

apparently, there could be an issue with make, but I didn't searched more on this (no time...).

So basically, I copied the content of 'build/lib.solaris-2.10-i86pc-2.6' into 'lib-dynload' and it worked.

Hope it helps.

Regars,
JeeP